# Detection of Windows 11 in Firefox (or any browser that doesn't support Client Hints)

Tags: javascript, firefox, user-agent, windows-11

I trying to detect Windows 11 using javascript without using this:

```
navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues
```

My reasons:

1. Is not supported in many browsers
2. It requires async programing which is not always convenient
3. It requires HTTPS

I know there are some questions about this, but none of them has any solution that doesn't use the User-Agent Client Hints.

Is this possible or we basically can't detect the newer versions of Windows anymore?

Comment: I don't have windows 11 so I can't try, but what does plain `userAgent` get you?

Comment: It would be of interest to my curiosity why you would need this in a browser vs just knowing if a browser supports a given functional need.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Statistical purposes.

Comment: @MattEllen - Windows 11 and Windows 10 have the same userAgent: Windows NT 10.0